# bash: cd: /opt/ts3soundboard: Permission denied

Tags: bash

I have modded `/opt/ts3soundboard/` with :

```
chown musikbot:musikbot /opt/ts3soundboard
```

But the user can't access it? Why's that? I can access it as root user.

```
root@euve102733:~# chown musikbot:musikbot /opt/ts3soundboard/
root@euve102733:~# su musikbot
musikbot@euve102733:/root$ cd /opt/ts3soundboard
bash: cd: /opt/ts3soundboard: Permission denied
```

Comment: if you don't mind, can't you just post the output of `ls -lad /opt/ && ls -lad /opt/ts3soundboard/`

Comment: Output of `ls -ld /opt` please. The chances are that `musikbot` doesn't have any access to that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the user has permission problems with /opt itself. You should set proper permission for user on /opt  or try it like this just for testing:

```
   chown -R musikbot:musikbot /opt/ts3soundboard

 and 

   chmod 744 /opt/ts3soundboard
```

Comment: Still not working. root@euve102733:~# chown -R musikbot:musikbot /opt/ts3soundboard
root@euve102733:~# su musikbot
musikbot@euve102733:/root$ cd /opt/ts3soundboard
bash: cd: /opt/ts3soundboard: Permission denied
musikbot@euve102733:/root$

Comment: Ok , Answer updated

Comment: Thank you, it worked after some problems, do you also know the problem here? xinit: XFree86_VT property unexpectedly has 0 items instead of 1
xinit: Unable to run program "/opt/ts3soundboard/ts3bot": Permission denied
Specify a program on the command line or make sure that /usr/bin
is in your path.

xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down

Comment: https://forum.sinusbot.com/threads/problem-to-start-the-bot.929/